# Creating dynamic pysimplegui tab

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysimplegui

I am trying to create a dynamic pysimplegui where I can add input box in the 2nd tab based on the entry from the inputs in the first tab from the user. That is if the user inputs 3 in the first tab then in the 2nd tab there will be 3 input boxes. Below is the sample code I am having. But this has error. Please help in correcting the error.

The error is occurring the updating the tab in the below lines:

```
tab2.update(tab2_layout=tab2_layout)
```

Below is the full code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

# Define the layout for the first tab
tab1_layout = [
    [sg.Text("Enter the number of input boxes you want to add:")],
    [sg.InputText(key='-NUM_INPUT_BOXES-')],
    [sg.Button("Submit", key='-SUBMIT-')],
]

# Create the first tab
tab1 = sg.Tab("Input", tab1_layout)

# Initialize the second tab layout as an empty list
tab2_layout = []

# Create the second tab but keep it disabled until needed
tab2 = sg.Tab("Dynamic Input Boxes", tab2_layout)

# Create the tab group
tab_group_layout = [[tab1, tab2]]

# Define the main layout with the tab group
layout = [
    [sg.TabGroup(tab_group_layout)],
]

window = sg.Window("Dynamic Input Boxes", layout, resizable=True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    if event == '-SUBMIT-':
        try:
            num_input_boxes = int(values['-NUM_INPUT_BOXES-'])

            # Define a layout for the dynamic input boxes
            tab2_layout = [[sg.Text(f"Input Box {i + 1}:"),
                           sg.InputText(key=f'-INPUT_BOX_{i}-')] for i in range(num_input_boxes)]

            # Add a "Submit" button to the dynamic layout
            tab2_layout.append([sg.Button("Submit", key='-SUBMIT_DYNAMIC-')])

            # Update the second tab with the dynamic layout
            tab2.update(tab2_layout=tab2_layout)

            # Create a new window with the updated layout
            updated_layout = [[tab1, tab2]]
            window.close()
            window = sg.Window("Dynamic Input Boxes", updated_layout, resizable=True)

        except ValueError:
            sg.popup_error("Please enter a valid number for input boxes.")

    if event == '-SUBMIT_DYNAMIC-':
        # Retrieve values from the dynamic input boxes
        input_values = [values[f'-INPUT_BOX_{i}-'] for i in range(num_input_boxes)]
        sg.popup("Input Values", input_values)

window.close()
```

Comment: Where you found that you can call method `tab2.update` with an option `tab2_layout` ? There's no such option for it, don't guess how it called.

Comment: The [`psgtest` application](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/psgtest) uses dynamic Tabs.  You will need to use the `TabGroup.add_tab` call.  There is no `Tab.update` parameter to add a layout to a Tab.  That's done when you make the Tab.

Comment: @MikefromPSG, please help to give me the full updated code based on your suggestion. I am not getting the right direction.

Comment: Please open a GitHub issue